# Working out the direction of undirected arcs in a learned structure using bnlearn

Tags: r, bayesian-network

I'm using the Dublin census data to test out bnlearn. If anyone wants the data, I'm using the processed data (data_train) from this [self organising map tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTaY2.png).

All the columns are actually the values in their original units. e.g. internet percentage ranges from 0 to 100. Number of cars from 0 to 4 (it allows for decimal places because it's an average of a particular area, rather than one row per individual).

I simply imported the data and used iamb function in bnlearn to learn the structure, then used mle to fit.

The problem is, when I look at the structure, there are so many undirected arcs. There is a function called pdag2dag that turns partially orderd DAGs into ordered DAGs, when you provide a list of orderings.

But how am I supposed to work out that list of orderings? With so many undirected arcs...

[image: DAG with undirected arcs]

Comment: constraint learning algorithms can only learn up to the equivalence class of a BN -- `?bnlearn::cextend` provides a way to coerce this to a dag .. or you could use a score based algorithm.